# Confluent BigQuerySinkConnector Schema Registry error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I try to create Kafka to BigQuery data pipeline using Confluent BigQuerySinkConnector. Test environment is a [cp-all-in-one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxC9e.png) docker container. I added on it (it does not exist as default). All definitions I did on Google BigQuery side (I hope...). But it just gives Schema Registry error that I cannot understand why it occurs. I created a table which is named as rest_avro on BigQuery dataset. The topic schema:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "User",
  "type": "record"
}
```

I defined this schema on BigQuery table manually.

[image]

There is no error when connector running.

[image]

My connector configuration is loaded successfully

```
[2020-08-19 13:21:46,803] INFO SinkConnectorConfig values:
    config.action.reload = restart
    connector.class = com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector
    errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
    errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
    errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
    errors.log.enable = false
    errors.log.include.messages = false
    errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
    errors.retry.timeout = 0
    errors.tolerance = none
    header.converter = null
    key.converter = null
    name = kcbq-connect1
    tasks.max = 1
    topics = [rest-avro]
    topics.regex =
    transforms = []
    value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SinkConnectorConfig)
[2020-08-19 13:21:46,803] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
    config.action.reload = restart
    connector.class = com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector
    errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
    errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
    errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
    errors.log.enable = false
    errors.log.include.messages = false
    errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
    errors.retry.timeout = 0
    errors.tolerance = none
    header.converter = null
    key.converter = null
    name = kcbq-connect1
    tasks.max = 1
    topics = [rest-avro]
    topics.regex =
    transforms = []
    value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig)
[2020-08-19 13:21:46,804] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=compose-connect-group] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2020-08-19 13:21:55,940] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-kcbq-connect1-0, groupId=connect-kcbq-connect1] Seeking to offset 8 for partition rest-avro-0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer)
```

But console puts errors like below. Do you have any idea?

```
[2020-08-19 13:09:45,663] ERROR Task failed with org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException error: Exception encountered while trying to fetch latest schema metadata from Schema Registry (com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.KCBQThreadPoolExecutor)
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-79" org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exception encountered while trying to fetch latest schema metadata from Schema Registry
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.schemaregistry.schemaretriever.SchemaRegistrySchemaRetriever.retrieveSchema(SchemaRegistrySchemaRetriever.java:67)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.updateSchema(SchemaManager.java:58)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.attemptSchemaUpdate(AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.java:129)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.performWriteRequest(AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.java:96)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.BigQueryWriter.writeRows(BigQueryWriter.java:117)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.TableWriter.run(TableWriter.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:153)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:188)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getLatestVersion(RestService.java:359)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getLatestVersion(RestService.java:351)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getLatestSchemaMetadata(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:136)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.schemaregistry.schemaretriever.SchemaRegistrySchemaRetriever.retrieveSchema(SchemaRegistrySchemaRetriever.java:63)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem says that BigQuery Sink Connector is unable to retrieve the current schema from Schema Registry container.

It seems that the *schemaRegistryLocation* field has been misconfigured on BigQuery Sink connector properties. Most probably it has been set to be *http://localhost:8081*.

As the docker-compose.yml shipped with [Confluent's repository](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/6.0.0-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml#L52) says, this endpoint needs to be defined as *http://schema-registry:8081* on dockerized environments.

With below properties I managed to create the BigQuery Sink Connector;

```
{
  "name": "customer-connect1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "dbserver1.venue_organization.customers",
    "topicsToTables": "dbserver1.venue_organization.customers=customers",
    "sanitizeTopics": "true",
    "autoCreateTables": "true",
    "autoUpdateSchemas": "true",
    "schemaRetriever": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.schemaregistry.schemaretriever.SchemaRegistrySchemaRetriever",
    "schemaRegistryLocation": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "bufferSize": "100000",
    "maxWriteSize": "10000",
    "tableWriteWait": "1000",
    "project": "venue-organization",
    "datasets": ".*=venue_organization",
    "keyfile": " /data/venue-organization-service-account.json"
  }
}
```

More in here: [Google BigQuery Sink Connector Configuration Properties](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-bigquery/current/kafka_connect_bigquery_config.html)